# How to load images always from a common path in NextJS

Tags: next.js, next.js13, nextjs-image

Next JS version used:12.2.4

I have a subdomain (say bikes) ,which is a part of a main domain(say vehicles). Using proxy, when someone enters vehicles.com/bikes, they are redirected to our application.

In our NextJS project, we have defined a route "bikes". So vehicles.com/bikes will show up our page.The issue is ,it was not able to pickup the asset files. So we added an assetPrefix (like '/two-wheelers') and wrote a rewrite function to change all "/two-wheelers/_next" requests to "/_next" requests and "/two-wheelers/images/*"  to /images/*". Now js ,css is loading fine. But the images are behaving weirdly.
In landing page, the images are coming up fine. When I open Networks tab, the url of some images are "two-wheelers/_next/static/media/imageName.png". Then there are some images with url "two-wheelers/images/imageName.png". This is also fine. Then the rest of the images are not loading. Their url does not have this assetPrefix. They are hitting the main domain directly( url is vehicles.com/_next/image?url=...). In all these cases, i have imported the images in the same way by giving public path location in Image src. So why are the images being fetched from different URLs.
I tried adding path property in next.config.js. Now the images which are not loading have this path in their url(3rd url).
How can i make sure that all images are fetched from the assetPath or a constant location?.
Why does 3 different URLs exist :

1)*two-wheelers/_next/static/media/imageName.png*

2)*two-wheelers/images/imageName.png*

3)*two-wheelers/_next/image?url=*